# How can i solve the launching error that appers after the installation of pycharm?

Tags: java, python, pycharm

i have a problem, when i'm trying to run pycharm it appears a lunching Error:

" Failed to load JVM DLL\ bin\server\jvm.dll
If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in.   Computer > System Properties > System settings > Enviroment Variables. "

Problem is that i don't have any JDK installed on my computer and as far as i know it's not required to have it to install pycharm...
(I have a 32bit windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/install-and-set-up-pycharm.html)

> JRE for 32-bit systems is not bundled with PyCharm. If you are using a
>   32-bit version of Windows, select the Download and install JRE x86 by
>   Jetbrains checkbox in the installation wizard to automatically
>   download and install JRE.

So, when installing in the Wizard you have to specify to download Java JREx86